# How to tell if a Less file is in sync with the compiled CSS file

Tags: css, less

I have been handed over a website that uses LESS to pre-process CSS.  I need to update some styles, but I'm not sure if the previous developers had been modifying LESS files and then compiling the CSS, or if they lazily had just been editing the CSS directly.
I want to edit the LESS but I'm worried that I'll lose any changes the previous devs made to the CSS directly.
I don't know who the previous developers were or have access to their source control to see the file history.

Is there any way to check if the LESS file is in sync with the CSS file?

Comment: Do a compile and then compare the files? Just make sure you back up the current files and you should find out soon enough...

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to reproduce LESS file from CSS file.

Try to keep a copy of the CSS file and try to compile again. Then compare the two CSS files.